# What Azure blobService method is most appropriate for storing JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, azure-blob-storage

This is the documentation I've been following, 
https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html

I have some short JSON strings that need to go into the BLOB storage for longer term and more efficient storage. I am unsure where they would be stored as block, page, or append BLOBs, and whether or not to upload from text, from a stream, or a local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your requirement for **"for longer term and more efficient storage"** , all the method would be apt as it fills the criteria for durable storage. But considering that you have a small size json string which you want to store , i would suggest you to use page blob.

Page blobs are a collection of 512-byte pages optimized for random read and write operations. To create a page blob, you initialize the page blob and specify the maximum size the page blob will grow. To add or update the contents of a page blob, you write a page or pages by specifying an offset and a range that align to 512-byte page boundaries. A write to a page blob can overwrite just one page, some pages, or up to 4 MB of the page blob.

Azure virtual machine disks are backed by page blobs. Azure offers two types of durable disk storage: premium and standard. Premium storage for page blobs is designed for Azure virtual machine workloads that require consistent high performance and low latency.

For further reference please go through following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs